# Evaluate 2D point in a 3D triangle?

Tags: algorithm, coordinates, interpolation

Given three points,
(x1, y1, z1)
(x2, y2, z2)
(x3, y3, z3)

and given a point "A" at (x, y),
how would I find "A'", at (x, y, z)?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... Are you looking for the intersection of a plane (defined by three points) with a specific line parallel to the z-axis?

Comment: Intersection of a plane defined by three points, but find the Z with a given X and Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the library or technology you are working with - things can get easier. But it is *almost always* good to understand the maths behind this stuff. Have a look at the [line through plane equations on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection).